# wxPython's GLCanvas is not resized when maximizing frame

Tags: wxpython, pyopengl, maximize

I followed the tutorial of PyOpenGL to create a frame with 2 GLCanvas(es). When the frame was resized, the canvases work well (they filled all region of the parent. However, when I maximized, just the left one resized, the right one kept the old size although when I printed out the size, it displays the new size. Can anyone help me to fix this?
My code is as followed:

```
import wx
import sys
from wx import glcanvas, MAXIMIZE
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

class MyCanvasBase(glcanvas.GLCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        glcanvas.GLCanvas.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.init = False
        self.lastx = self.x = 30
        self.lasty = self.y = 30
        self.size = None
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # Do nothing, to avoid flashing on MSW.

    def OnSize(self, event):
        size = self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        if self.GetContext():
            self.SetCurrent()
            glViewport(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        event.Skip()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        self.SetCurrent()
        if not self.init:
            self.InitGL()
            self.init = True
        self.OnDraw()

    def OnMouseDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        self.x, self.y = self.lastx, self.lasty = evt.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, evt):
        self.ReleaseMouse()

    def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            self.lastx, self.lasty = self.x, self.y
            self.x, self.y = evt.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh(False)


class CubeCanvas(MyCanvasBase):
    def InitGL(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glFrustum(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -2.0)

        glRotatef(self.y, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glRotatef(self.x, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

    def OnDraw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 0.0,-1.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 0.0,-1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)

        glNormal3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f( 0.5, 0.5,-0.5)

        glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5,-0.5)
        glEnd()

        if self.size is None:
            self.size = self.GetClientSize()
        w, h = self.size
        w = max(w, 1.0)
        h = max(h, 1.0)
        xScale = 180.0 / w
        yScale = 180.0 / h
        glRotatef((self.y - self.lasty) * yScale, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef((self.x - self.lastx) * xScale, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        self.SwapBuffers()

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, title = "PyOpenGL Example 1"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
                self, parent, id, title, size = (400,200),
                style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | MAXIMIZE
        )

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box.Add(CubeCanvas(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(CubeCanvas(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.SetSizer(box)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
frame = MainWindow()
app.MainLoop()

del frame
del app
```

Comment: I don't use OpenGL, but do you really need the OnSize event, can't you just let the sizers do their job?

Comment: OnSize is just called after sizers do their job and it just changes the view by updating matrices in OpenGL. OnSize will not affect to the display of windows. I tried to remove the event but the same problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in MainWindow.**init** function when I called Frame.**init**(...) with wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE which prevents the redrawing of whole window. Remove this will solve the problem